# how to make a dataframe out of an array of case class in scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

Say, I have : case class Rows(column: String,operation: String,result: String)
I created a array buffer and stored objects of type Rows in it.
How to convert this into a dataframe

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here are some references to help you ask questions on SO -- [ask], [mcve], [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8279585)

Answer (score 0):

Given a case class definition and a spark session you could use `createDataFrame`:

```scala
case class A(_a: String, _b: String, _c: String)

val rows: ArrayBuffer[A] = ??? //or any Seq[A]
val spark: SparkSession = ???

spark.createDataFrame(rows)
```